# omxplayer rtsp stream over composite output

Tags: ssh, video, composite-video

I only manage my pi over ssh.

Finally I successfully tested a rtsp stream over hdmi with:

```
sudo omxplayer -o hdmi rtsp://<ip-address>/<streamname>/
```

How can I play a video or a stream with omxplayer over the yellow composite output?
I didnt find any infos about this.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> How can I play a video or a stream with omxplayer over the yellow composite output?

Note that `-o hdmi` refers to the *audio* output (see `omxplayer --help).

The video output will be the active one for the system.  Making the composite active may be as simple as plugging it in, unplugging the HDMI, and rebooting.

If that does not work, or you want a more detailed answer to the question, *How do I select the active video output?* then ask that as a separate question.